# Implementing unlimited pipes in C with just one loop and one pipe

Tags: c, shell, while-loop, pipe, execvp

I'm trying to build a minishell and I've mostly everything but pipes working. I've read a lot of answers in this site and many others, but I'm not able to find my particular problem.

The sequence should end when the right-most process ends, this is: `sleep 3 | sleep 3 | sleep 0` should immediately end, and not wait for any of the sleep 3 processes.

*argvv is a pointer to the first process (*argvv would be `sleep 3`, *(argvv + 1) is the next `sleep 3`, etc. I don't know what's going on, but something is wrong with file descriptors and everything breaks after a test.

For instance, when the input is `sh> ls | wc | wc`, the output is

```
sh> ls | wc | wc
sh>    1       3      25
```

, then it waits for some input. It's not until I press enter again it finishes. After that, `sleep 3` does not work anymore.

Any help would be welcome, thanks a lot!

**Edit:**

Ok, I edited the code and everything seems to work fine, except sleep 3 | sleep 0 lasts 3 seconds, instead of immediately ending. I don't know how to fix this.

```c
void execute(char ***argvv)
{
    pid_t pid;
    int pd[2];
    int in = 0;

    while (*argvv != NULL) {
        pipe(pd);
        
        if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
        {
            perror();
            exit(1);
        }
        else if (pid == 0) {
            dup2(in, 0);
            if (*(argvv + 1) != NULL)
                dup2(pf[1], 1);
            close(pd[0]);
            close(pd[1]);
            execvp((*argvv)[0], *argvv);
            perror();
            exit(1);
        }

        else
        {
            close(pd[1]);
            in = pd[0];

            if (*(argvv + 1) == NULL)
                close(pd[0]);
            argvv++;
        }
        wait(&pid);
    }

}
```

Comment: Och, a fellow [three star programmer](https://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer)! `if (argvv == NULL)` I think is wrong. `something is wrong with file descriptors and everything breaks after a test.` Please show what is wrong and what breaks and what tests are you running. Please create an [MCVE].

Comment: @KamilCuk gotcha! I edited the post fixing what you told me and adding an example. Thanks!

Comment: The function presented is a little sloppy in that it creates one more pipe than it actually needs or uses, and in that it leaves the read ends of all the pipes open indefinitely in the parent process.  That latter, at least, is a serious problem: it's a form of resource leak that can cause breakage pretty quickly.

Comment: There is also a pid leak of you do not provide for either collecting each child with one of the `wait`-family functions or transferring that duty to some other process -- for example, double `fork`ing to get process 1 to take on that responsibility.

Comment: Hello again @JohnBollinger. Thanks again for your time. I added some new info to the post and my changes. Unfortunately, it's not really working as expected, and I'm not sure I'm closing every file descriptor with the new code.

Comment: concerning your last edit, please read 
[**How should we treat posts that are vandalized by their original authors?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/106812/251777)

Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on Stack Overflow, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the CC BY-SA 4.0 license for Stack Overflow to distribute that content. By Stack Overflow 

policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: If you want to know how to delete your post, take a look at 
[**How does deleting work?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that/5222#5222)

Answer (score 1):

I think part of the problem may be in the use of `wait()`.  It's pid parameter is an OUTPUT, reporting which `fork()`ed process ended.  Every forked processed ends, and needs to be `wait()`ed for.  When you run a second pipeline, all but one piece of the preceding pipeline is still ready to be `wait()`ed for.

Generally, you have several choices:

1. `wait()` in a loop until the process you want to end ends.
2. `wait()` in a loop until all the subprocesses end.
3. Use `waitpid()` to look for a particular process ending.
4. Arrange that only the last process in the chain is a child of your process, making the rest children of that.  (This is done by some shell, though I don't remember which.)  The problem with this is that it leaves extra children for the last process in the chain, which may confuse it.
5. Track all the child processes, and which have ended.  When you background a pipeline, this allows you to display which parts of the pipeline are still running.  (tcsh does this.  bash does half.)
6. `fork()` twice for the earlier pipeline members, `execvp()` in the grandchild, then `exit()` in the child, and have the parent `wait()` for the child to finish before going on.  This disconnects the grandchild from the parent, so it never needs to be waited for.
7. Do things involving ignoring `SIGCHLD`, but this will probably cause you a lot of grief, as it is all or nothing.

Comment: Hey! Appreciated answer, thanks for your time. How would that explain the pipe not working with two commands but not with three? It brokes with two pipes and waits for input after the last execution. :(

Comment: @Lexuchrist  I missed it before: you incremented argvv too early.  Or alternatively, must account for the increment in the if statement after it.

Comment: @Lexuchrist there might also be issues from not sufficiently closing the pipes.  None should be left open when you get to the wait().  Note that you may safely close it after dup2()ing it.

Comment: Hello again! I fixed some stuff (you can check it on the main post) and it kinda works, but it's not really working as intended. It should end when the right-most command ends, and it currently waits the `sleep 3` before it to end.

Comment: Since you moved the wait() call out of the conditional, you also need to move it out of the while loop.  Currently, you wait for each child after you make it, which means you wait for the sleep 3, then wait for the sleep 0.  If the first process output a lot of data, it would get blocked writing to the pipe and never finish.  You are also still doing wait(&pid) ... and that is still an output variable.

Comment: I missed that too...  It is `int status; int pid2 = wait(&status);`